# setting 'Timespan' value to the first 'Time' value in the first 'Batch' where subject was not included

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, shift

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9YlA.png)

```
Jacob,19,Male,True,1654949111,0,1
Anna,20,Female,True,1654949111,0,1
Jacob,19,Male,True,1654949222,0,2
Anna,20,Female,True,1654949222,0,2
Brother,20,Male,True,1654949333,0,3
Anna,20,Female,True,1654949333,0,3
Cleitinho,53,Female,True,1654949444,0,4
Jacob,19,Male,True,1654949444,0,4
```

Each 'Batch' is a web scrape.
I want to put the value in the 'Timespan' column on each 'Name'.
To the value in the 'Time' column in the first next 'Batch' that 'Name' was not included in.

Should 'Name' appear in a later 'Batch', the procedure must be repeated. . . .

Also it would be nice if 'Name' is present in several consecutive 'Batch' to just remove the entries inbetween the first and last.

On the last 'Batch', the value for 'Timespan' should be 'Time' + 1 second.

```
Jacob,19,Male,True,1654949111,1654949333,1
Anna,20,Female,True,1654949111,1654949444,1
Brother,20,Male,True,1654949333,1654949444,3
Cleitinho,53,Female,True,1654949444,1654949445,4
Jacob,19,Male,True,1654949444,1654949445,4
```

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beOut.png)

Answer (score 0):

On the last 'Batch', the value for 'Timespan' should be 'Time' is still not included.

How i solved it for now:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('names.csv',names=['name','Age','Gender','Online','time','Timespan','Batch'])
names = data[['name', 'time', 'Batch']].copy()

df_dict = names.groupby(names.Batch.values).agg(list).to_dict('records')

scrapes = [pd.DataFrame(df) for df in df_dict]
sessions = pd.DataFrame(columns=['session', 'name', 'login', 'logout'])
for i in range(len(scrapes) - 1):
prev_scrape = scrapes[i]
current_scrape = scrapes[i+1]    
# Add a new sessions for all users that where not online last scrape
for _, current_name in current_scrape['name'].iteritems():
    if prev_scrape[prev_scrape['name'] == current_name].empty:
        # Find at which batch the user went offline
        for scrape_to_check_if_still_online in scrapes[i+1:]:   
            if scrape_to_check_if_still_online[scrape_to_check_if_still_online['name'] == current_name].empty:
                new_entry = {
                    'session': len(sessions[sessions['name'] == current_name].index),
                    'name': current_name,
                    'login': current_scrape['time'].iloc[0],
                    'logout': scrape_to_check_if_still_online['time'].iloc[0]
                }
                sessions = sessions.append(new_entry, ignore_index=True)
                break
```